# Make multiple OSC signals into single one

Tags: machine-learning, networking, port, osc

I have the following OSC addresses giving me data: 
/wii/acc/x 
/wii/acc/y 
/wii/acc/z

I need it for a program that receives one line as OSC inputs.
Is there any notation to send all as one signal? I tried this:
/wii/acc/x, /wii/acc/y, /wii/acc/z (Not spaces allowed)
/wii/acc/ (Address not open)
/wii/acc/[x, y ,z]

If there is no such way to send a signal, do you know any program or way to convert all three signals into one. For Linux.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I modified the program that generates the signal. 
I used a WiiMote and WiiOSC http://www.nescivi.nl/wiiosc/